# Can we use an n-channel MOSFET instead of a p-channel?

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

Can we use an n-channel MOSFET in the place of a p-channel? In my configuration I'm using a 12 V 40 W solar panel for charging a 12 V, 7.5 Ah lead-acid battery.

in this configuration it should be p-channel mosfet for switching which gives positive voltage to battery for charging. Here I have common ground from input voltage and Battery, so I'm unbale to switch to n-channel mosfet. but p-channel mosfet are very difficult to get in the market.

so my question is can I use n-channel mosfet to pass positive voltage from source to drain? e.g. if I use STP80NF55

[image]

Comment: Not as drop-in replacement at least. This schematics would require some reworking to make it work with n-channel mosfet with such signal from IC.

Comment: Can you help if I provide original schematics?

Answer (score 2):

> *so my question is can I use n-channel mosfet to pass positive voltage
> from source to drain?*

An N channel device as shown in your diagram will pass current from source (the positive input voltage) to drain (the 1N5822) quite naturally because an N channel device has an internal parasitic diode that always allows this: -

[image]

The symbol for the N channel device in the picture (left) has a diode that connects between source and drain so it will naturally allow a flow of current from source to drain when the source is a little bit more positive than the drain. This diode is present internally in all regular MOSFETs.

So, that's the good news. The bad news is that you can't disable that diode and it will always conduct current to the load from the supply. In other words, the circuit is no longer effective as a switch and that is why the original (and correct) diagram used a P channel MOSFET.

However, if you were to switch source and drain around and used a more complicated drive circuit that could apply a gate voltage higher than the incoming supply (maybe up to 10 volts higher), then an N channel device could be used but, to be honest, and for simplicity, I'd try and find a suitable P channel device and stick with the original idea.

Comment: You can "disable" the diode by putting two MOSFETs back to back pointing in opposite directions.  This is the standard configuration for USB-C Power Delivery systems.

Comment: @AndrewLentvorski you'll still need to drive the gate of one of those MOSFETs higher than the incoming supply voltage by up to 10 volts (as mentioned in my answer) for two MOSFETs to be effective. And also, as it happens, using 2 MOSFETs would be a poor solution because, due to the battery polarity being constant and incoming supply always being polarized the same way, one MOSFET is redundant so, take a step back and think what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

That's why most battery and solar controllers have positive common and switch the negative. If you are not that much constrained, try changing to common positive.

In order to switch positive side with N-channel MOS, you need some kind of charge pump driver that will drive the gate with a voltage positive than the source and the drain.

See here: [Charge Pump-Based Gate drive supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/473411/charge-pump-based-gate-drive-supply)

This approach adds complexity (bad always) and power consumption (bad mainly in battery-powered things).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect not.  The problem with an n-channel MOSFET is that the gate needs to be a threshold voltage (Vt) above the terminals in order to turn on.

So, your solar panel puts 12V on the source and your battery leaves 12V on the drain and your gate is a maximum of 12V.  The transistor in that case is off.

You would need to put 12V+Vt on the gate to turn the transistor on.  Most n-MOSFET drivers have a circuit called a "bootstrap" in order to generate the slightly higher gate voltage required to turn on an n-MOSFET used as a "high side driver".

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, it needs to be several volts higher than the threshold voltage to properly turn on. And not above "the terminals" but, above the source terminal. Also, for static switching applications, a bootstrap circuit is not effective because it relies on the MOSFET switching on and off quite often in order to replenish the capacitor that gets charged higher than the incoming power rail. Think again.

Comment: @ Andrew lentvorski .Remember that many mosfets are specified to conduct 1 mA at Vgs th .So you will need much more to get amps with low volt drops .I think that you could change the wording of your Answer to avoid spurios downvotes .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use a bootstrap circuit with the n-channel MOSFET. Then you will be able to use it as a high side switch.

Comment: It would be helpful if you'd add or link to an example circuit.